# How to edit a file's properties after is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I'm using the uploadify jquery plugin to upload multiple files. Everything works fine, but i want something a little more from the script. I want to add some more info to the uploaded files. How do I remove the default behavior of the onComplete option and instead of removing the file queue item from the list, to display a thumbnail of the uploaded file with some form elements for editing that item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask is not an illegal manipulation, Graza has misunderstood probably.

Anyway to your answer, you get on "onComplete" event "event and file details" and by knowing them you can fire a function inside onComplete and create your forms after file upload is completed.

hope it helps,
Sinan.

from its doc:

> onComplete
>
> A function that triggers when a file upload has completed. The default function removes the > file queue item from the upload queue. The default function will not trigger if the value > > of your custom function returns false.
>
> Four arguments are sent to the
> function:
>
> event: The event object.
>
> queueID: The unique identifier of the
> that was completed.
>
> fileObj: An object containing details
> about the file that was selected.
>
> response: The data sent back from the
> server.
>
> data: Details about the file queue.

Comment: Aha, yes that makes sense. I think the key here is your observation that you need to return false to prevent the default from executing - it sounds like he's aware of (and probably passing in) an onComplete method, just not returning false to prevent the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the uploadify plugin does, but I can tell you that browser/web security will not allow any client-side manipulation of (or even *access* to) client-side files. You'll need your server-side app/script to pass back data from the files once they are uploaded if you want to be able to do any reading or manipulation of them from the browser....

Browser extensions/plugins may allow this, but a javascript library certainly won't.